# Error when saving data in iPhone SDK 4.2

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, save

Here is some code that I'm trying to make save some `UITextView` text. When I run it and change the text and click the save button it works but when I take it from the multitasking bar it and open it back up, it crashes. Whats wrong?

```
- (NSString *)saveFilePath
{
    NSLog(@"saveFilePath");

    NSArray *path =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];

}
```

(The save file.plist is on my project file)
view did load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

    if (fileExists)
    {
        NSLog(@"file Exsists");

        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        notesTextView.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
    }

}
```

Save data button:

```
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:notesTextView.text, nil];
    [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Crashes with what ? Post CRASH Log.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it crashes the application. Heres the crash log from the console: sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place in the code you've posted that could cause a crash is the line:

```
notesTextView.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
```

If the array is empty (has zero items in it) this will crash with an array out of bounds error. I suggest you put:

```
if ([values count] > 0)
{
    notesTextView.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And see if your crash goes away.

In an unrelated note, you can actually simplify your code quite a bit by taking out the "if (fileExists)" part by just using [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:...] which safely returns nil if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks very much, but for some reason it's still crashing:-(. I'm confused in that the text is being saved and displayed when I remove it from the multitasking bar and open it back up but for some reason it still crashes, confusing hey!

Comment: It sounds like it's unrelated to the code you've pasted into the question. Is this in the simulator or on the device? Is anything being logged to the console? Have you tried enabling break on exceptions and zombies?

Comment: do you mean 'enabling break on exceptions and zombies' by doing a instruments session? and it's in the simulator, do you want me to try it on a Device, by the way thanks very much for the help :-)